# why mouse is slow? (mouse hide flash as)

Tags: flash, hide, mouse

That code when I use hiding cursor. But while moving the mouse is slow. 
How can I fix it?

```
Mouse.hide();
cursors.onMouseMove = function() {
    this._x = _xmouse;
    this._y = _ymouse;
    updateAfterEvent();
};
```

thanks.

Comment: What is this supposed to be? Javascript?

Comment: Hello. You added a tag for "hide" and a tag for "mouse", but no tag for "flash". Anyway, I added it.

Comment: Is this code inside another bigger function? Is it inside an enterFrame function? What happens if you replace all the above code with this: `cursors.onMouseMove = function() { Mouse.hide(); }`

Comment: There's a simple animation of the movie clip. 
Thank you for your interest.